# Jupiter moon phase in pyephem

Tags: pyephem

I am bit of a beginner with all this, but I've search around and can't find an answer.

I was to work out the phase of Io, as per [this](http://www.spaceacademy.net.au/spacelab/projects/jovrad/jovrad.htm).

Where *"The position or phase of Io (γIo) is measured counterclockwise around its orbit from Superior Geocentric Conjunction (SGC)"*

I am current using:

`moons = ephem.Io()`

`moons.compute(t)`

`print moons.x, moons.y, moons.z`

Is there a way I can get the phase out of `jupmoon.c`? I am assuming that it has an elliptical orbit so it isn't as easy as simply working out the coordinates of x,y,z on a circle about the centre of jupiter?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the phase of Jupiter itself as the phase of any of its moons, since Jupiter and its moons are close enough together in the sky — and close enough together in space relative to the position of the Earth — that there should be no observable difference in phase between Jupiter itself and the moons that surround it when viewed from the Earth.